# git deployment to windows machine

Tags: windows, git, deployment

I am developing scripts for stimulus presentation in an experiment in cognitive neuroscience (in a proprietary language). 'Deploying' these scripts simply means copying them to the desktop of a Windows 7 machine in a laboratory, from where different experimenters can launch them. This machine lives inside a VPN and can connect to the internet, but it is not always turned on and only turned on at irregular intervals and logged into by different user accounts. I have admin rights on it, physical access only a couple of times per week.

I would like to use git+github but am wondering how to implement the 'deployment' in such a workflow. One idea would be to install git on the 'production' machine and use the windows task scheduler to a 'git pull' of the master branch on every boot / regularly. It would have to be invisible to the current user of the machine (no UAC prompt or possible error popup) and not impact system performance; importantly, if my experiment is currently running, the files should not be touched. If this is viable, what would be a good way to make the pulls visible in the git history as deployments, including the information whether any changes were pulled? The sequence would be like this:

```
changes to develop branch -> merge develop into master (maybe tag it with a version number) -> time goes by -> 'production' machine does a git pull
```

The next time the experiment is conducted, the changes of this version will be in effect.

This would mean that sometimes there are tagged versions of the master branch that never make it onto the production machine because I pushed a newer version before the production machine was turned on again.

Comment: Instead of launching the experiment directly and scheduling the `git pull`, you could create a simple "launch" program that pulls the most recent experiment and then launches it.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too. this will include minor re-education of the experimenters but seems like the most clean solution. I will also heed the advise given [here](http://gitolite.com/deploy.html). However, I would be interested in other options that do not involve running a script before starting the experiment. I could also try to set up the PC in the lab as a remote and have a script living on another server that periodically checks whether the 'production' pc is online. However, I do not now much about continuous deployment and don't really know where to start.